# How can I create a copy of a table in Redshift WITHOUT DATA but with all the table schema (like compressions and sort keys etc.)

Tags: mysql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to create a copy of a table in redshift without data? However, I want all the table schema (like compression, data types for each column sort keys and primary keys) to remain the same.

Answer (score 5):

Check `LIKE` option for `CREATE TABLE` statement in the docs: [CREATE TABLE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html)

It doesn't preserve primary key but it duplicates columns and sort/dist keys like this:

`CREATE TABLE new_table (LIKE existing_table);`

This is the best you can get unless you keep the original DDL statement somewhere and just re-execute it with a new table name.

Comment: Maybe the documentation on the CREATE TABLE was updated after this post because it actually says you can preserve the DEFAULTS when creating a table based on a LIKE:
CREATE TABLE new_table (LIKE existing_table INCLUDING DEFAULTS);